# Merging two datasets based on the 2 columns, or finding the missing values in first dataframe and filling that from the other

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have 2 pandas data-frames, with 2 columns namely index and date. Some of the dates are missing from the first data-frame, and those values can be obtained from the second data-frame corresponding to the index. I tried using pd.concat, pd.merge and pd.join etc but those doesn't seem to give me the results that I want. Here is the table.

df1 = [image: data-frame 1]

df2 = [image: data-frame 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there was no reproducible dataframe, I tried the code below with running on generated data, but I think it would work fine for your code too:

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"date": [None, None, None, "01/01/2022"], "index":[402,402,403,404]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["16/05/2020", "18/07/2021", "13/08/2022", "26/07/2020"], "index":[402,405,403,404]})
df1.set_index("index", inplace=True)
df2.set_index("index", inplace=True)
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
  if row["date"] != row["date"] or row["date"] == None:
    df1.loc[index , "date"] = df2.loc[index]["date"]
df1
```

##### Output

| index | date |
| --- | --- |
| 402 | 16/05/2020 |
| 402 | 16/05/2020 |
| 403 | 13/08/2022 |
| 404 | 01/01/2022 |

Note that `row["date"] != row["date"]` is used when a value of a cell is `nan` and has the type of float. `nan` values are not equal even to themselves!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried df1 = df1.update(df2)?

Although the update funtion will not increase the size of df1, it only updates the missing values or the values that were already there.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't do anything much. Returns an empty dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# initialize list of lists
df1 = [[402, '15/05/2020'], [408, np.nan], [408, '14/05/2020']]
df2 = [[402, '16/05/2020'], [408, '10/05/2020'], [409, '13/05/2020']]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=['index', 'date'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns=['index', 'date'])

df1.set_index("index", inplace=True)
df2.set_index("index", inplace=True)
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row["date"] != row["date"]:
        row["date"] = df2.loc[index]["date"]
```

**Output:**

```
index            
402    15/05/2020
408    10/05/2020
408    14/05/2020
```

With this solution only the rows whose date is `nan` or `null` are updated with the corresponding value on the other dataframe.